# How to modify a question (or other methods) to have it re-opened

Tags: discussion

How do I ask John Conde how to modify [this question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/27045/why-is-scoopex1988-org-not-indexed-by-search-engines) to re-open it? 
Since the site doesn't show up in any search engine and I ask general advice, I don't agree that it fits the closed-thread-description in the orange Closed As box. How do I point another moderator's attention to this thread for a second opinion?

I also put a lot of effort in ruling out problem reasons and give enough info, and I've seen similar threads. Will it help if I replace the name of the site in the title with 'my website', as for the other threads I saw?

Since the xhtml validates and no search engines index it, I would think it would be of very general interest!

Comment: I'd like to give an answer to the general question. I can flag it for reopen, but then I've got a lot of reputation. Can users with 101 rep see a "flag" link on their own closed questions?

Answer (score 2):

I have reviewed the question and I agree with John Conde.  Many times people new to the site can be confused by what too localized means.

Using Jeff's words:

> too localized
>
> This question would only be relevant to a very small geographic
>   minority, and is not generally applicable to the worldwide audience of
>   the internet.

The issue is that you are asking the community to go to your site and spend possibly a large amount of time reviewing your code for an unknown issue.  The truth is, you will very likely not get an answer that is helpful to you and if you do it will probably not be helpful to anyone else.

With that in mind I know you came to the site to look for help and we do want to help you.  Your best bet is to ask a new question that is much more concise and does not ask users to visit your site an analyze your code.  What you could ask for is a list of what ways someone can submit their site to Googl/Bing (this probably has already been asked) and then ask another question about general issues that would cause Google not to search your site.

Also, as an aside, you should look at Google Webmaster.  It is free and it will let you submit your account and once Google crawls your site it will give you a report of any errors it may have run into.  Again, this would be specific too you so no one can really help you since only you can setup a Webmasters account for your site.

Comment: I have opened a question at google webmaster groups, however I disagree that users would have to look at the code as it validates. As I wrote, those were speculations and I don't speculate. I also think the answer would be a generic one that would help others and for all search engines, as no articles at all are indexed - not only the front page. Submitting the site ot search engine is the opposite of a general solution and would NOT help others with the same issue. If there's a rule that one's site should never be mentioned, well, then it's a rule but it also rules out many webmaster queries.

Answer (score 2):

The fact that your site is not being indexed is a symptom of an underlying problem.

```
wget http://scoopex1988.org
--2012-03-10 01:56:50--  http://scoopex1988.org/
Resolving scoopex1988.org... 91.186.20.51
Connecting to scoopex1988.org|91.186.20.51|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 301 Moved Permanently
Location: http://scoopex1988.org/1.html [following]
--2012-03-10 01:56:50--  http://scoopex1988.org/1.html
Reusing existing connection to scoopex1988.org:80.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 500 Internal Server Error
2012-03-10 01:56:51 ERROR 500: Internal Server Error.
```

You have a very specific server configuration issue - this is likely a misconfiguration (or malware) and, therefore, the solution to the issue will only be applicable to others with the same issue *after* they are able to determine the source of the issue.

You may be able to find assistance with configuration issues at [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/) (if you are willing to post relevant configuration information and log data), however, malware recovery tends to require expert intervention beyond the scope of a concise answer or set of instructions.